# Google App Engine and JPA, building a tree structure with entities

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, entities

Hi I'm trying to build an application as homework which involves a database. For this database we need to use JPA and since we're using the Google App Engine I need my entity classes to be well structured.

We have 6 entity classes that need an underlying relationship, namely Car, CarRentalCompany, CarType, Quote, Reservation and ReservationConstraints. I was trying to model the following tree structure: CarRentalCompany being the root and since this class holds a collection of cars and cartypes it got me thinking the relationship should be like this

```
    @Entity
    public class CarRentalCompany {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private long id;

      private String name;
      @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "carRentalCompany")
      private Set<Car> cars;
      @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "carRentalCompany")
      private Map<String,CarType> carTypes = new HashMap<String, CarType>();

    ...
    }

    @Entity
    public class Car{

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       private Key id;

       @ManyToOne
       private CarRentalCompany carRentalCompany;

    ...
    }

    @Entity
    public class CarType{
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private Key id;

      @ManyToOne
      private CarRentalCompany carRentalCompany;

    ...
    }

    @Entity
    @MappedSuperclass
    public class Quote implements Serializable {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private long id;
      @Temporal (TemporalType.DATE)
      private Date startDate;
      @Temporal (TemporalType.DATE)
      private Date endDate;
    ...
    }

    @Entity
    public class Reservation extends Quote {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private long id;
      private long carId;

      @ManyToOne
      private Car car;
    ...
    }
```

The problem is I keep getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException of which I was told that it means something is wrong with the entity model. Could someone point out my error?

**EDIT: the compiler throws the error when I try to close the entitymanager (em.close())
It also gives me the following warning:

Meta-data warning for ds.gae.entities.Car.carRentalCompany: Error in meta-data for ds.gae.entities.Car.carRentalCompany : The datastore does not support joins and therefore cannot honor requests to place related objects in the default fetch group.  The field will be fetched lazily on first access.  You can modify this warning by setting the datanucleus.appengine.ignorableMetaDataBehavior property in your config.  A value of NONE will silence the warning.  A value of ERROR will turn the warning into an exception.**

```
public static Set<Car> loadData(String name, String datafile) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {

    EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    Set<Car> cars = new HashSet<Car>();
    int carId = 1;

    //open file from jar
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(CarRentalServletContextListener.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(datafile)));
    //while next line exists
    while (in.ready()) {
        //read line
        String line = in.readLine();
        //if comment: skip
        if (line.startsWith("#")) {
            continue;
        }
        //tokenize on ,
        StringTokenizer csvReader = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
        //create new car type from first 5 fields
        CarType type = new CarType(csvReader.nextToken(),
                Integer.parseInt(csvReader.nextToken()),
                Float.parseFloat(csvReader.nextToken()),
                Double.parseDouble(csvReader.nextToken()),
                Boolean.parseBoolean(csvReader.nextToken()));
        //create N new cars with given type, where N is the 5th field
        for (int i = Integer.parseInt(csvReader.nextToken()); i > 0; i--) {
            Car c =new Car(carId++, type);
            cars.add(c);
            try{
            em.persist(c);
            }finally{
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }

    return cars;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where exactly are you getting the exception? My crystal ball is a bit fuzzy lately

Comment: I've added some more details and a code snippet. In short: i'm getting a warning telling me the datastore does not support joins and therefore cannot honor requests to place related objects in the default fetch group.

Comment: A little off-topic, but I strongly recommend you to NOT use any relational-database-to-object frameworks in App Engine. Cold start performance and strange behaviours (to traditional relational databases) are the main reasons, but you can read more about it [here](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Concepts).